# How do I enter ':after' into my html?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have placed 3 social media icons into my website, where I want to create a coloured background for each icon.  The coloured background needs to come in two parts.  The first being a straight forward rectangle with the second part requiring some further editing in order to create the desired effect.

As such, I need to be able to style the ::after element.  I have looked in my source code but cannot see it anywhere.  I can see the ::before entry but not the ::after.

The concerned code is:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3" id="social-media-icons">
        <i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-fw fa-lg" id="facebook-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-fw fa-lg" id="twitter-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-instagram fa-fw fa-lg" id="instagram-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

How can I go about entering the ::after entry?  Would I be right in understanding that whilst such an entry appears in the html, you do not actually edit the html directly?

Comment: This would need to be done in CSS , Not html

Comment: My CSS is a bit rusty but if I remember right :after is not an item that literally exists in the DOM, it refers to a "pseudo-element", meaning whatever it is that comes after the element being referred to.

Comment: @GordonM is right. It's a "pseudo element", meaning "not a real element." You create it in CSS like `.someSelector:after {}`

Comment: Thanks for both of your insights.  So would I be right in saying that :after would not exist unless I stated it in the stylesheet?  I have just tried this and it seems to work but just want to make sure I have understood the process behind it. :-)

Comment: Hey Craig. Was your question answered by one of the answers below? Then feel sure to accept one of them to indicate that your problem has been solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's done in CSS using a pseudo element.

For example:

```
i::after {
  ...
}
```

Demo: http://www.codeply.com/go/2M4sgYmTw6

Answer (score 0):

`::before` and `::after` (you should use `::`, a single `:` is only supported for legacy purposes) are so called [pseudo elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) - they dont exist in the source code but are inserted once your CSS is processed.

You can style it, by simply defining it in the style sheet. Because of this special behavior, additionally to the normal declarations, you have the option to define its `content`. Often this would be just static content, but the cool thing is, that you have the possibility to generate dynamic content as well!

```css
    span::before{ 
      content: "☺";
      color:blue;
      font-size:150%;
    }

    div::after{
      content: "dynamic content: "attr(data-value);
    }
```

```html
<span> Hello </span>
<div data-value="Foo"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight, especially regarding the use of '::'.

Comment: You are welcome! Feel free to give an upvote of approval ;-)